# How to get button name added on UniformGrid runtime?

Tags: c#, wpf, button, uniformgrid

Get `Button` name added on UniformGrid during run time.

My code is:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= no; ++i)
{
    Button button = new Button()
    {
        Content = i,
        Tag = i,
        Background = Brushes.White,
        Height = 30,
        Width = 30,
        Name="A" + i.ToString() 
    };

    string name=button.Name;

    button.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(button_Click);
    this.grid1.Children.Add(button);

    if (name.Equals("A1"))
    {
        button.Background = Brushes.White;                    
    }                   
}
```

My requirement is to get `Button` name in other function:

```
private void Sum()
{
}
```

Here is my XAML:

```
<UniformGrid x:Name="grid1" Margin="816,115,96,354" Grid.Column="1" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't clear what is the ultimate goal here. But you can loop through all child of `UniformGrid` which type is `Button` to get name of each button and take action accordingly :

```
foreach (var btn in grid.Children.OfType<Button>())
{
    var btnName = btn.Name;
    //take action according to button name
}
```